# How to use Angularjs to dynamically set spinner after table row bound

Tags: angularjs

I'm updating the table via an ajax call, and want to display a spin.js spinner while the row.status == pending. 
Basically I have a row fragment that successfully toggles from

```
 <div class="spinner">
```

to

```
 <div class="hide">
```

as the row computation progresses, (via ajax within a controller).
I'm happy with any mechanism that works! 
What I'm struggling to do is, when the value is

```
 <div class="spinner">
```

have a spinner showing, otherwise have it hidden.

```
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>url</th>
                    <th>status</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>                 
                <tr data-ng-repeat="row in result.results">
                    <td>{{row.link.url}}</td>
                    <td> <div loadingWidget class="{{(row.status == 'pending' ? 'spinner' : 'hide' ) }}"></div>{{row.status}}</td>
                </tr>                   
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

My latest script - basically I don't really know what I'm doing,

```
app.directive('loadingWidget', function ($rootScope) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            field: '=',
            attributes: '=',
            editMode: '='
        },

        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.spinit = function() {
                $rootScope.$broadcast('spinit');
            }
        }
    };
});

$scope.$on('spinit', function(element){
    //react to event
    new Spinner().spin(element);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the ngHide directive. I'm having difficulty determining what you want your show/hide condition to be though. The rule is that if the contents of ng-hide evaluate to true, the element will be set to hidden.

If you absolutely need to switch the active class, not just hide the element, user ng-class. That will set the class based on a variable in scope.

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>url</th>
            <th>status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>                 
        <tr data-ng-repeat="row in result.results">
            <td>{{row.link.url}}</td>
            <td> 
              <div loadingWidget class="spinner" ng-hide="row.status"></div>
              {{row.status}}
            </td>
        </tr>                   
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Also, using $broadcast on root scope can be incredibly expensive, and is almost never necessary. In your case I don't see why you can't just call the Spinner().spin method directly.

ngHide docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide

ngClass docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Edit:
Okay, so I went through your code more thoroughly. You have several issues here.
First, you directives are kebab case in html, camelcase in javascript. That means your directive should look like: `<div loading-widget class="spinner" ng-hide="row.status">`.
Also, you have restrict E on your directive attributes. This means it can only be used as an element, and you are using it as an attribute. To fix this, either remove the restrict option or change it to `restrict: 'A'`.
You don't need the scope on your loadingWidget directive at all, and honestly any time you include Root Scope you are probably doing something wrong.
All of this results in a directive that looks something like this:

```
app.directive('loadingWidget', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            field: '=',
            attributes: '=',
            editMode: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log("elm: ", element[0]);
            new Spinner().spin(element[0]);
        }
    };
});
```

[Plunkr Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/HNSrSb9mhxooUVedr0OT?p=preview)

Also, there are already wrapper modules for Spin.js in Angular, so if you don't mind more dependencies that is a good option ([Link](https://github.com/urish/angular-spinner)).

In terms of the logic for hiding the spinner, I would simply use an ngShow with the value of whatever will be in that cell. When you go to update the value, set it to '' or false or undefined. On page load or when it gets changed to one of the values I just mentioned, the spinner will be hidden. Once the value is set, it will no longer be falsy and the element will show. This works as long as you never expect to store false in the variable. In Angular, don't use events unless you really need to, just manipulate scope variables and wait for the digest cycle. Having some simple state variables and then a combination of ngShow and ngHide can make simple state changes in a view easy.

A core value of getting comfortable with writing good Angular code is knowing that you basically never interact with your application outside of scope or directives. Avoid element selectors, and avoid events unless you are sure you need them. Much of Angular was designed to avoid the JQuery like tools, because they can make your code really hard to read.

Comment: Thanks for response, the problem I have is I cannot get the spinner to spin, the js event logic I'm using isn't actually causing an spin icon to display. I've an expectation that when the div is rewritten the spinner will disappear - I think. I unsuccessfully tried calling the Spinner().spin(element) within the link function.

Comment: fantastic, each row now has its own busy spinner. thanks for explanation & your time

Comment: No problem. Have fun with Angular, it's a joy.